# How to avoid Chrome's automaticDownload limitations

Tags: google-chrome, popup, microsoft-teams

I have a site that offers users the chance to download files by clicking a button which loads a rest request then uses file-saver to download it.

The second time a user in Chrome clicks this they get a popup blocker. The message is "This site attempted to download multiple files automatically". How does Chrome determine when to show this message? Can I do something to reset it?

The site is loaded as an iframe within microsoft teams. But I don't think that is the issue

[image: image shown]

Answer (score -1):

Fire up Chrome, click the menu icon, and then click “Settings.” Alternatively, you can type chrome://settings/ 
Once in the Settings tab, scroll down to the bottom and click “Advanced.”

Scroll down to the Privacy and Security section and click on “Site Settings.”
[image]

Scroll down the list of settings until you see the “Automatic Downloads” option. Click on it.
[image]

By default, the feature is set to ask permission when a site tries to download files in succession. This is the recommended behavior, but if you want to block all sites from downloading multiple files automatically, toggle the switch to the Off position.

[image]

Comment: Sorry you misunderstand me - I am designing the website and trying to avoid this issue

Comment: Did you ever work out a way, in your website design, to avoid the popup blocker?